# DIV fixed from an absolute position

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

This is an effect very seen but i dont know how to do it, i want to have a DIV in an absolute position, for example in the middle of the page
but when you scroll down and your "border-top" of your navigator touches the div, then it comports like with

```
position:fixed; top:0px
```

Is there any way to do it only with css3? I think i can do it with jQuery and changing classes dinamically, but I'm sure there is an easy way

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in plain CSS3 without Javascript/jQuery's help for at least a few reasons:

1. CSS is a language where you can only define *rules* that determine the appearance of HTML elements and cannot implement other programming concepts like *conditions, variables, etc*. [However SASS (Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets) does support the use of the aforementioned, but it lacks in so many things from Javascript, e.g. it cannot *listen* to events from DOM elements just as Javascript does.]
2. You need to *listen* to the *scroll event* when the page is scrolled (which isn't possible in CSS). For this *listening* to happen, you need to register a handler to *handle* the situation when that particular event is fired.
3. As soon as the current position from the top of the screen reaches some height (better known as `offset`) upon scroll, first, you may want to *calculate* that offset. Next thing you'd do is to *add* the style to the element which forces `position: fixed` on it. You could define the rule for this in CSS certainly, but yet again, you need Javascript's help to enforce this rule on the element.

Comment: Roger! So I'm going to do it in jQuery, thank you for the advice.